# Problem Creating png image of TextBlock using RenderTargetBitmap in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, rendertargetbitmap

When using **RenderTargetBitmap** to generate a PNG file from a **TextBlock** that is a child of a **Canvas**, the text is stretched to match the width of the TextBlock. The TextBlock has a TextAlignment set to 'Right'. However, the generated PNG does not accurately represent the rendered TextBlock.

The sample code below produces images where the text is cut off. I understand that the issue arises from setting the left and top properties of the text. Could you explain why this happens and suggest a solution?

```
Canvas innerCanvas = new Canvas();
innerCanvas.Width = 500;
innerCanvas.Height = 500;

TextBlock textBlock1 = new TextBlock
{

    Width = 87,
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"),
    FontSize = 13.00,
    Foreground = Brushes.Black,
    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right,
    Text = "TEXT1"
};

TextBlock textBlock2 = new TextBlock
{
    Width = 87,
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"),
    FontSize = 13.00,
    Foreground = Brushes.Black,
    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left,
    Text = "TEXT2"
};

Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock1, -70);
Canvas.SetTop(textBlock1, 0);

Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock2, 50);
Canvas.SetTop(textBlock2, 0);

innerCanvas.Children.Add(textBlock1);           
innerCanvas.Children.Add(textBlock2);

innerCanvas.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
innerCanvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), innerCanvas.DesiredSize));

double dpi = 96;
double dpiScale = dpi / 96; // Adjust the dpi scale

foreach (UIElement child in innerCanvas.Children)
{
    if (child is TextBlock textBlock)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap bmpCopied = new RenderTargetBitmap
        (
            (int)Math.Round(textBlock.ActualWidth * dpiScale),
            (int)Math.Round(textBlock.ActualHeight * dpiScale),
            dpi,
            dpi,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32
        );

      
        bmpCopied.Render(child);

        var pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpCopied));

        String imageName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\temp\Images", textBlock.Text + ".png");

        using (var stream = new FileStream(imageName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            pngEncoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing the DrawingVisual code and rendering the TextBlock directly seems to resolve the test case. However, I have another case where the text is cutoff.

Comment: Did you intend to render the Canvas instead of the TextBlock? Otherwise the whole Canvas stuff would be pointless here. Or do you just want to create a bitmap with some text with certain margins?

Comment: The example represents a simplified version of the state that a real world scenario exists in where I traverse the visual tree to get to the textblock and then create an image of it. However in my real world scenario the visual tree is much deeper and the image created was either stretched the to the width of the textbox or if not using a visual brush the text was cut off inside the textbox.

Comment: I edited the scenario above to more accurately reflect the problem.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Because I was working with the textblock itself and not it's parent, I ended up cloning the TextBlock where the clone did not have left and top values set and then creating the image from the clone. This gave me accurate image of the textblock, which is what I needed. I was getting these textblocks out of  a diagram that contains many layers of uielements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because of Width and Left values that you set for the TextBlock. I tried to replicate your code in Xaml and in this picture you can see what went wrong.

[image]

I guess Instead of `TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right,` you mean to set the Horizontal Alignment of the TextBlock. in that case this is what you need:

```
TextBlock textBlock1 = new TextBlock
 {
     Width = 87,
     FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"),
     FontSize = 13.00,
     Foreground = Brushes.Black,
    // TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right,
     Text = "TEXT2"
 };

 textBlock1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;

 Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock1, 0);
 Canvas.SetTop(textBlock1, 0);
```

Also if you want to give the TextBlock some margins from left or right, you should consider the alignment of the element.
When it aligned to right in order to add some space from the left edge of Canvas you can use **Canvas.SetLeft** a posetive value and when it aligned to the right you can set the value of **Canvas.SetRight**.